# Date formatting in php?

Tags: php, date

I have a text box that a user needs to type a date into. When a user types, say, 21 Jun 2014 it works great. When a user just types a year however, it changes what the user inputted to the current date.

Code:

```
    $bday = strftime("%m/%d/%Y", strtotime($_POST['bday']));
    $eyb = strftime("%Y", strtotime($_POST['bday']));
    $em = strftime("%m", strtotime($_POST['bday']));
    $ed = strftime("%d", strtotime($_POST['bday']));
    $emd = strftime("%m/%d", strtotime($_POST['bday']));
    $eya = $eyb + 110;
    $edate = $emd . "/" . $eya;
```

I would like the code to automatically change the date to the last day of the year if all they provide is a year.

I have tried checking if $em isset, but that doesn't work because $em $ed and $eyb all have values = to the current day. For example, if I were to type just 1904 in the form field $eyb, $em, and $ed would be = to 2014, 07, 30 respectively.

What is wrong here?

Comment: You're just throwing `$_POST['bday']` into your code without checking what values it has and reacting accordingly.

Comment: @user1954544 The date is automatically inputted from an external API. I just need to know the format of the date.

Comment: @JohnConde I just took a few minutes to google how I can check the date format of $_POST['bday']. How would you check to see if it only contains a year?

Comment: @blazerunner44 you can use a regex to check if its only a year and act accordingly

Comment: Why can't you do this client side with Javascript?